# Using not exist in mysql to find IDs not yet assigned

Tags: mysql

I have a `locnew` table that has names of all locations in a warehouse so :

```
1 | acb1
2 | acb7
3 | aba2
```

i also have a `location` table which will assign products to the locations so it will have a locnew id (`location_description_id`) and then all the details of the products. I have wrote this query to show all the items in each location :

```
select l.*
     , ln.location_description 
  from location l
  join locnew ln 
    on ln.id = l.location_description_id
 where l.location_description_id != 376
```

which gives me everything we have in stock in them locations

[image]

Is there a way to use not exists to reverse this so i can find a list of all the "locnew" id's that dont have any products assigned to them in the location table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left join

```
select l.*, ln.location_description 
    from location l
    left join locnew ln 
    on ln.id = l.location_description_id
    where ln.id is null
```

Joins are conceptualized as set operations in math.

When you join, you are taking the intersection of two sets.

When you left join, your are taking the intersection of two sets plus the remaining members of the left (first table) set.

When you right join, your are taking the intersection of two sets plus the remaining members of the right (second table) set.

However as you see, NONE of these three options give you what you need. What you need is the remaning items in the left set. This is why ln.id is null is added to the where clause. When there is not record on the right side, ln.is becomes null and the query gives you what you need.

Comment: you may give a bit of explanation about what is the difference between inner and left join and why this is useful for OP needs

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM locnew ln
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM location
                 WHERE location_description_id = l.id)
```